# App Header using React Native Paper shows a top padding in Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper, react-navigation-v6

I am having this issue on Android where the `App.Header` component in React Native Paper shows a `paddingTop` in Android, in iOS looks great. I have attached 2 screenshots to show what I'm talking about...

Android:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

This is my code in the SettingsScreen.js file:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerMode: "screen",
        header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Appbar.Header style={appStyles.appBar}>
                <Appbar.Content titleStyle={appStyles.appBarTitle} title={t("dashboard.header")} />
                <Appbar.Action
                    icon={() => <AntDesign name="calendar" style={appStyles.appBarIcon} />}
                    onPress={() => {
                        datePicker.show();
                    }}
                />
            </Appbar.Header>
        )
        });
    }, [navigation]);
}
```

Any tips will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this issue by adding statusBarHeight={0} to Appbar.Header.

```
<Appbar.Header style={appStyles.appBar} statusBarHeight={0}>
```